# How to update UIBezierpath and CAShapeLayer path with pan gesture of UIView?

Tags: swift, animation, draw, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

'''

```
import UIKit

class CanvasView: UIView {
    var circleViewTag = 1000
    var coordinatePoints: [String] = ["243,103","534,86","243,286","426,286"] {
        didSet {
            self.updateCoordinateArray()
            self.drawPoints()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate var coordArray: [CGPoint] = []
    var shape = CAShapeLayer()
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    /*// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }*/
    
    private func drawPoints() -> Void {
        CommonMethods.printLog("\(coordinatePoints)")
        self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
        shape.opacity = 0.5
        shape.lineWidth = 2
        shape.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.miter
        shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
        
        if let firstCoord = self.coordArray.first {
            path.move(to: firstCoord)
        }
        for (index, cgPoint) in self.coordArray.enumerated() {
            self.drawCircularPoint(points: cgPoint)
            if index == 0 {
                continue
            }
            path.addLine(to: cgPoint)
        }
        path.close()
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        //self.drawLineBetweenPoints()
    }

    
    private func drawCircularPoint(points: CGPoint) -> Void {
        
        let circleView = UIView.init(frame: .zero)
        circleViewTag = circleViewTag + 1
        circleView.tag = circleViewTag
        circleView.frame.size = CGSize.init(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
        circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        circleView.center = points
        circleView.backgroundColor = .random()
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.draggedView(_:)))
        panGesture.view?.tag = circleView.tag
        circleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        circleView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        self.addSubview(circleView)
    }
    
    @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        guard let getTag = sender.view?.tag else { return }
        if let viewToDrag = self.viewWithTag(getTag) as? UIView {
            var currentPoint: CGPoint = .zero
            if path.contains(viewToDrag.center) {
                print("YES")
                
                currentPoint = path.currentPoint
                
            }
            
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self)
            viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + translation.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + translation.y)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
            
            if sender.state == .began && currentPoint != .zero {
                let coordinateIndex =  self.coordArray.firstIndex { (cgpoint) -> Bool in
                    if currentPoint == cgpoint {
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                }
                
                if coordinateIndex != nil {
                    self.coordArray[coordinateIndex!] = viewToDrag.center
                    self.shape.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    self.path.removeAllPoints()
                    self.setNeedsDisplay()
                    
                    self.layer.addSublayer(self.shape)
                    self.shape.opacity = 0.5
                    self.shape.lineWidth = 2
                    self.shape.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.miter
                    self.shape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                    self.shape.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
                    
                    
                    if let firstCoord = self.coordArray.first {
                        path.move(to: firstCoord)
                    }
                    for (index, cgPoint) in self.coordArray.enumerated() {
                        //self.drawCircularPoint(points: cgPoint)
                        if index == 0 {
                            continue
                        }
                        path.addLine(to: cgPoint)
                    }
                    path.close()
                    shape.path = path.cgPath
                }
                
                
            }

        }
        //self.bringSubviewToFront(viewDrag)
    }
    
    private func updateCoordinateArray() -> Void {
        for singleCoordinate in self.coordinatePoints {
            if singleCoordinate.contains(",") == true {
            
                let splitCoordinate = singleCoordinate.split(separator: ",")
                
                if splitCoordinate.count == 2 {
                    let xPos = CGFloat(Float(splitCoordinate[0]) ?? 0.0)
                    let yPos = CGFloat(Float(splitCoordinate[1]) ?? 0.0)
                    let cgPoint = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)
                    
                    self.coordArray.append(cgPoint)
                }
            }
        }
        
        var penultimateIndex: Int?
        if let penultimateCoordinate = self.coordArray.penultimate() {
            penultimateIndex =  self.coordArray.firstIndex { (cgpoint) -> Bool in
                if penultimateCoordinate == cgpoint {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
        var lastIndex: Int?
        if let lastCoordinate = self.coordArray.last {
            lastIndex =  self.coordArray.firstIndex { (cgpoint) -> Bool in
                if lastCoordinate == cgpoint {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }
        if penultimateIndex != nil && lastIndex != nil {
            self.coordArray.swapAt(penultimateIndex!, lastIndex!)
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]
'''

I am creating a polygon using UIBezierpath and CAShapelayer. Added pan gesture on all 4 points that is UIView. When I drag the point A,B,C,D the expected behaviour is that bezierpath and CAShapelayer gets updated with the updated points. And when user drag the inner part of the shape all the path gets updated. But I am unable to update the path and shape. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

yon set name for layer

```
var shape = CAShapeLayer()
shape.name = "name1"
```

and then, instead of updating, you can delete it by first searching by name, and then add